# Laptop not working on any battery

Tags: windows, laptop, battery

I had a problem with battery in my laptop (laptop hibernate or crash randomly when on battery). The laptop is a Clevo N957TP6.

So after sometime I bought a new battery. the battery has a part number of N950BAT-6 (6-87-N85KS-61D02 BAT.P S LI 11.1V/5.6AH/62WH 3S2P SMP/LGC (TEXTURE) CQC (BQ30Z55)) - 980Q2204F.

It worked fine for sometime, but now the problem is back again.

I want to ask what cound possibly the problem be, and how can I diagnose the issue?

Note: I tried to gather some logs. Battery manager sometime report weird charge level sometime (sometime very little to sometime 600%)

Answer (score 2):

Try [resetting battery charging](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/clevo-150em-wont-charge.716049/), *which is specific to the make and model and OS*. Generally,

- Open *Device Manager* and uninstall the ACPI battery charging driver.
  [image: Uninstall Battery Charging Driver]
- Shut down Windows *completely* (not Fast Start or Hibernate).
- Remove the battery.
- Unplug the power supply.
- Hold the laptop power button for ~30 seconds.
- Reinsert the battery.
- Plug in the power supply.
- Reboot.

Check *Device Manager* to see that the ACPI driver automatically reinstalled; if not, right-click *Batteries* and `Scan for hardware changes`.