# My laptop does not turn on

Tags: sony-vaio

My Sony VAIO laptop doesn’t turn on with or without battery. I left it in sleep mode yesterday and now I can not turn it on.

I can remember while saving a photo on Photoshop it showed some error regarding RAM. I have no idea if it is anything to do about that or not.

I tried to press and hold the power button for ~30 seconds and it still did not work.

Comment: Remove all power (battery and mains) and leave it for ~10 minutes. If it still does not turn on after that then you'll need to investigate further. Are there any beeps, LEDs flash, fans spin, etc..? Is the RAM correctly seated?

Comment: @Attie no beeps, no LED flash, fans spin etc. Seems like it’s dead

Comment: No fans normally means dead PSU or motherboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Attie stated, remove all power, and also, while powered down, hold the power button for about a minute to bleed any charge in capacitors.

Leave the battery out, plug in the power supply and try to boot. If that fails, try to enter BIOS. If either work, it shows that you may have depleted the battery so badly the laptop cannot boot from it. It *might* be possible to recharge it by leaving it plugged in for a day with power off, or by [resetting battery charging](https://superuser.com/questions/1374851/laptop-not-working-on-any-battery). However, Li-ion batteries deteriorate rapidly when left discharged, so it may need to be replaced.